# If I have data that appears normally distributed, but it contains a lot of zeros, are there issues with assuming a normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

Suppose I have the following data where the data looks normal but contains a lot of zeros. For example, I generated half of the data as standard normal and half as zeros. Does this cause us to run into any issues when considering things like hypothesis tests, etc?

```
mydata <- c(rnorm(500),rep(0,500))
```

[image]

Comment: The first question you need to ask if your data contains a lot of zeros is "Is this [zero-inflated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) data?" If it is, use methodlogy designed for zero-inflated data.

Comment: I don't think this is currently a good question for two reasons: firstly, the example distribution does not actually look normal at all. Secondly, it is a very theoretical question. You could write a lot how specific tests and estimated do under those circumstances, but for real world data this is much less important than understanding the data generation process which should guide the analysis anyway. Of course, a purely theoretical question can have merit, but then it needs to have a more specific scope and a correct title in my opinion.

Comment: For what it is worth, the fact that the data is a mixture of zeroes and a normal distribution with mean zero probably makes it a bit more robust when using location tests which technically require normality or a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no sense in which I'd be tempted to claim that this "appears normally distributed" per the title - it is clearly *really* far from normally distributed; it looks like what it is --  a mixture of a spike and a continuous distribution.

[image: empirical cdf of another set of data generated in the same way, with a normal distribution for comparison; the data has a large jump and heavier tails]

As for how much it matters, that very much depends on the situation. For example, if you were testing equality of variances, I wouldn't suggest you try assuming normality. On the other hand, a test relating to the upper tail of the distribution might not be all that much impacted by the spike.

Comment: If we wanted to do hypothesis tests, should I stay away from t-tests and go with non-parametric tests such as rank sum tests?

Comment: @user321627, what do you mean by "hypothesis tests"? Note that Glen_b says he wouldn't assume normality when testing equality of variances.  That's a hypothesis test. You may be thinking of a test of location (mean).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes I am thinking of a test of location.

Comment: It''s unfortunate that you didn't consider specifying that you wanted to know about location tests in particular before someone answered your question. Are we looking at one or two sample tests? What sort of alternatives are of particular interest? e.g. are you interested in a tendency to be larger (like $P(Y>X) \neq\frac12$; are you specifically interested in some simple location parameter like mean or median? or if you're contemplating a shift, is it only the non-zero values that shift in your alternative? Does the proportion of 0's change under the alternative? ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... Might the spike be at an undetermined value (rather than at a known value like 0)? What sorts of sample sizes might we be dealing with? There's much to consider here. In relation to the "etc" in your question, what other things might we consider?

Comment: By way of example, if we're considering pure location-shift alternatives (i.e. the whole distribution moves along the number line without changing shape or the spike proportion at all) then an obvious strategy is to simply identify the location of the spike. One only requires that the probability of at least a few values at the spike being in the sample is large (you will have this if the population proportion at the spike and the sample size are not both small) and the power of this test will be much better than assuming normality or using some "standard" rank-based nonparametric test. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... You could do this for example by finding the gaps in the order statistics. $x_{(2)}-x_{(1)},x_{(3)}-x_{(2)},...,x_{(n)}-x_{(n-1)}$. The modal difference will be for the order statistics that are at the spike. There would be ore sophisticated approaches possible (i.e. exploiting more of the information), but this will be enough to demonstrate that we shouldn't just ignore knowing that the variable has a spike in it (knowledge of the variable's properties should come prior to looking at the data, since the test being used should not depend on what you observe in the data you want to test)

Comment: If, however, the spike *doesn't* move nor change proportion under the alternative, then we'd probably want to focus on the values that *can* move and in that case (after removal of the part that doesn't change) more typical tests might indeed be useful.  So even when dealing with location, it still very much depends on the specific circumstances.